# Como acessar um objeto aninhado em outro objeto dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, react, ecmascript-6

Eu tenho o seguinte JSON

```
{
   "Id":"ssjsjs",
   "Name":"STFksks S.A",
   "Alias":"STF jnsns S.A",
   "DocumentId":"010101",
   "Accounts":[
      "hahadkjkjteste"
   ],
   "CountryCode":"BRA",
   "Country":"Brasil",
   "Address":{
      "PostalCode":"222222",
      "Street":"Largo dos Leões",
      "State":"RJ",
      "City":"Rio de Janeiro",
      "Country":"Brazil",
      "Number":"200",
      "Complement":"",
      "Neighborhood":"Humaitá",
      "AddressType":"Comercial"
   },
   "TestContracts":[
      {
         "Name":"Teste nome",
         "Email":"teste@teste.com.br",
         "Phone":"55219999999",
         "PhoneCountry":{
            "DialCode":"55",
            "Format":"+..-..-....-....",
            "Iso":null
         }
      },
      {
         "Name":"hsshsh",
         "Email":"teste2.teste",
         "Phone":"5521981660129",
         "PhoneCountry":{
            "DialCode":"55",
            "Format":"+..-..-....-....",
            "Iso":null
         }
      },
      {
         "Name":"hahah",
         "Email":"shshs@asd.sdf",
         "Phone":"552121212122",
         "PhoneCountry":{
            "DialCode":"55",
            "Format":"+..-..-....-....",
            "Iso":null
         }
      },
      {
         "Name":"Gus",
         "Email":"ddsds@jjjj.com",
         "Phone":"33333333",
         "PhoneCountry":{
            "DialCode":"55",
            "Format":"+..-..-....-....",
            "Iso":null
         }
      }
   ],
   "PaymentType":0,
   "PaymentStatusChangeDate":"2017-08-05T14:24:32.6503311Z",
   "PaymentStatus":0,
   "InscricaoMunicipal":"002",
   "InscricaoEstadual":"",
   "UnblockPaymentStatusRequest":"",
   "WillBlockAt":"",
   "Tier":"",
   "ChargeStrategy":"Active",
   "Address.PostalCode":"2226021"
}
```

Eu faço uma função para monitorar os dados que são modificados ao digitar algo no input, pegando o id do input que está sendo alterado, e modificando o valor para o novo valor digitado.

```
  handleInputChange(event) {
    const { Company } = this.state
    Company[event.target.id] = event.target.value
    this.setState({ Company: Company })
  }
```

Mas quando tento acessar as propriedades do objeto `Address` da seguinte maneira, recebo undefined:

```
 handleInputChange(event) {
    const { Company } = this.state
    const targetId = event.target.id

    if (targetId.includes('.')) {
      const targetIdSplit = targetId.split('.')
      const targetIdSplit0 = targetIdSplit[0]
      const targetIdSplit1 = targetIdSplit[1]
      console.log(Company[targetIdSplit0].targetIdSplit1)
    }
  }
```

Eu não consigo entender o porquê. Quem puder me mostrar a maneira certa de acessar esse objeto, eu agradeço muito.

Comment: Tens de usar `[]` para `targetIdSplit1` também, para teres dois niveis de chaves dinamicas: `Company[targetIdSplit0][targetIdSplit1]`. Se não fôr isso dá um exemplo de `event.target.id`.

Comment: @Sergio, deu certo. Muito obrigada mais uma vez. S2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de usar `[]` para `targetIdSplit1` também, para teres dois níveis de chaves dinâmicas:

```
Company[targetIdSplit0][targetIdSplit1]
```

Quando tinhas `Company[targetIdSplit0].targetIdSplit1` o código ia procurar uma propriedade de nome `targetIdSplit1` em `Company[targetIdSplit0]` e não o valor que a variável `targetIdSplit1` guardava. Ou seja o código lia `targetIdSplit1` como texto e não como uma variável.